# api call getting affected by another api call's validation

Tags: node.js, api, express

not really sure if my title is correct but my problem is that I have this reset password token checker in my api that seems to get affected by another api that finds a specific user, this api has user validation.

Here is what they look like:

```
//get specific user
router.get('/:id', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const user = await User.findByPk(id);
    res.json(user);
});

//reset-password token check
router.get('/reset-pass', async (req, res) => {
    await User.findOne({
        where: {
            resetPasswordToken: req.body.resetPasswordToken,
            resetPasswordExpires: {
                [Op.gt]: Date.now()
            }
        }
    }).then(user => {
        if(!user) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Password reset link is invalid or has expired.'})
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                username: user.username,
                message: 'Password reset link Ok!'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

then here is the validateToken

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.cookies['access-token'];

    if (!accessToken) 
        return res.status(401).json({error: 'User not authenticated!'});

    try {
         const validToken = verify(accessToken, JWT_SECRET)
         req.user = validToken;
         if(validToken) {
            req.authenticated = true;
            return next();
         }
    } catch(err) {
        res.clearCookie('access-token')
        return res.status(400).json({error: err}).redirect('/');
    }
};
```

when I comment out the get specific user api the reset password token check works. If I remove validateToken it returns null instead of giving me the username and message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things I notice is the route param "/:id", that means that literally **everything** would be processed by get specific user because all routes start with "/", only use params in routes with a prefix like "/user/:id" that way only the routes that starts with "/user" will execute that code.

Change your code to:

```js
//get specific user
router.get('/user/:id', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const user = await User.findByPk(id);
    res.json(user);
});
```

Comment: this works lol! My bad I didn't notice this mistake! As soon I looked at my code again after posting I saw this problem too! Anyway, this is the correct answer! It thought 'reset-pass' was an id lol!